# Errors when upgrading to Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework

**package.json**

```
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
        "@ionic-native/core": "^3.4.2",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.4.2",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.2",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
        "ionic-angular": "3.0.1",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "rxjs": "5.1.1",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.0",
        "typescript": "~2.2.1"
      },
```

When I wanna change my version of Ionic from Ionic2 to Ionic3, I encountered some errors [image: below] Is it my version of @angular/core outdated or? [Sorry I could not copy and paste the errors here, only can snip a photo of it.]

Comment: Did you make changes as described https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300-2017-04-05 ?

Comment: Yes I did make the changes as described. Sorry for late reply.